# Targeting a background through css

Tags: css, wordpress, target

I am trying to target:

```
<div class="shapely-content dropcaps-content">
            <div id="paralaxdiv" class="paralaxclass"><section id="titleimageparalax" class="intense content-section parallax-scene parallax titleimageparalaxclass" data-anchor-target='#titleimageparalax' data-bottom-top='background-position: 0px 40px;' data--1000-top='background-position: 0px -80px;' data-height-adjustment="10px" data-speed="2" style="height:700px;   margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;  background-image: url(http://humatics.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/par_who_top-2-940x623.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-attachment: fixed;  padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom:25px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right:0px; overflow: hidden;"><ul id='parallax-scene-1973025556' class='parallax-scene-1973025556 parallax-scene'>
```

background-size: cover; and change it to 100%.  I can't figure out how to reach it to change the css from the wordpress custom code.  How would I target this bit of code?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use !important.

```
#paralaxdiv>section{
   background-size: 100% auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to change the background after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use javascript or jquery (I prefer jquery).

You would do it like so with jquery: `$("#titleimageparalax").css("background-color", "yellow");` for example.